# Solving quadratic matrix equation for $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, quadratics, matrix-equations

> $$X^2 = \begin{bmatrix}1&a\\0&1\\\end{bmatrix}$$ where $a \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$. Solve for matrix $X$.

---

I was practicing for matrix equations and this is the first one where it has squared matrix and another number, in this case, $a$. I would be grateful if you could help. If you can please suggest a book that has matrix equations to practice. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: Consider $X$ that looks like the matrix on the right (but with a different value in the upper-right entry), and compute $X^2$.

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera You can't diagonalize a Jordan block.

Comment: Sorry I realized I was mistaken but apparently did not delete it succesfully

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$M(a) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & a \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Note $M(a)$ has one eigenvalue: $1$, and is not diagonalisable. This means that, if $X^2 = M(a)$, then $X$ has eigenvalue $1$ or $-1$, but not both (if it had both, then $X$ would be diagonalisable, and so would $X^2 = M(a)$).
We also note that any eigenvectors of $X$ will be an eigenvector for $X^2$, and $X^2$ has only the eigenvector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$. Thus, $X$ must have only this eigenvector as well. (Of course, when I say a matrix has *only* one eigenvector, I mean that there is one eigenspace, and it is one-dimensional, so we can only find one linearly independent eigenvector.)

Now, multiplication by $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ on the right reveals the first column of a $2\times 2$ matrix. Therefore, the first column of $X$ is
$$X \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \pm 1 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \pm1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},$$
depending on whether the unique eigenvalue is $1$ or $-1$. This makes the matrix $X$ upper-triangular (due to the $0$ in the bottom left corner), so the eigenvalues of $X$ lie on the diagonal. That is, $X$ takes the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix} \pm 1 & * \\ 0 & \pm 1\end{bmatrix} = \pm\begin{bmatrix} 1 & * \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix},$$
where the three $\pm$s are all the same. That is,
$$X = \pm M(b)$$
for some $b$. Note that $(\pm M(b))^2 = M(b)^2$, so we are looking for $b$ such that
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^2 = \begin{bmatrix}1 & a \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix},$$
which was solved by Angel in their answer: $b = \frac{a}{2}$. This gives us precisely two solutions:
$$X = \begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{a}{2} \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, -\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{a}{2} \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Let $X = (I + N)$ where $I$ is the identy matrix and $N$ is the nilpotent matrix with all the diagonal entries and the lower left coner being zero. Take the second power of $X$, $$X^2 = I + N + N + N^2 = I + 2N $$ the answer is trivially obtained from that.